# Using ParameterType with table data?

Tags: cucumber

I'm using Cucumber with Ruby.

I have a [ParameterType](https://app.cucumber.pro/projects/cucumber-ruby/documents/branch/master/features/docs/writing_support_code/parameter_types.feature) which recognises money values and parses them to BigDecimal, e.g. "Given the cost is $25.50".

I would like to do something similar for tables, i.e anything which matches the pattern should be automatically converted, for example:

```
Given these products:
  | item | cost   |
  | foo  | $10.50 |
  | bar  | $5.25  |
```

I've not been able to find anything in the documentation about this. Is it possible?

EDIT: It seems this used to be supported with [Step Argument Transforms](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Step-Argument-Transforms) but these were removed in Cucumber 3:

> A table transform is matched via a comma-delimited list of the column headers prefixed with 'table:'

Comment: Do you mean the example table data or UI table data?

Comment: @supputuri I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Did you find a way? I'm looking to migrate a big test suite that heavily relies on table transformations.

Answer (score 0):

In the step definition make sure to iterate through all the items in the table and call the step `Given the cost is XXX`

Here is the sample logic in step def

```
And(/^Given these products:$/) do |table|
    # iterate through table
    table.hashes.each do |product|
       # you can get the product details here
       item = product['item']
       cost = product['cost']
       # you can use the item  if you want to select or any operation
       # calling the Given the cost is xx step (here calling the step that already you implemented)
       step("Given the cost is #{cost}")
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm really looking for a way for this to happen automatically across all tables, e.g. I call `product['cost']` and get a `BigDecimal` of `10.50` rather than a string `"$10.50"`.

Comment: Why don't you do the conversion with in 'Given the cost is xxx` step def or the method implement this. Optionally you can still convert the string to decimal using `to_i` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**August 2021**

According to [this Github Issue:](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/1551) after they replaced Transforms with ParameterTypes it's no longer possible to transform data tables.
The "official" workaround seems to be create a helper method: (original [#comment](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/1551#issuecomment-858156943)):

```
module Helpers
  def custom_transform(table)
    table.map_headers! { |header| header.downcase.to_sym }
    table.hashes.each do |row|
      # ...
    end
    table
  end
end

World(Helpers)
```

Then, in your step definintions:

```
Given /a step that takes a table:/ do |table|
  expand_placeholders_in table
  # ...
end
```